# Visual Studio not finding my DB as data connection

Tags: visual-studio, azure

I'm a newbie to programming, I'm trying to make a basic program which will write to a database, so I'm trying to follow Microsoft's own example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/data-tools/save-data-to-a-database-multiple-tables). I've created the sample database OK but I'm struggling with the *"Create the data source"* part. Firstly, the link about installing sample databases doesn't seem to actually have any information about sampling databases, so that's not a good start.

I tried to proceed with adding a data connection to the database but there's nothing in the dropdown when I try to choose a dataset.

I have the Azure Storage Emulator cmd prompt running and I've initialised to my MSSQLLocalDb but the 'start' command doesn't work. Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but I'm struggling with the "Create the data source" part.

I also follow the example that you mentioned. If we add the server **(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB** for the server name then we could see the databases listed in the dropdwonlist.
For more information you could refer the screenshot.

[image]
Then click next and choose the tables, we could get the expected result.

[image]